# What is JENKINS_HOME when Jenkins is installed via Homebrew?

Tags: jenkins, homebrew

I installed Jenkins via Homebrew and accidentally locked myself out (i.e. set up security before creating an admin-level user). [Instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) on the Jenkins wiki instruct me to remove some lines from config.xml that is located in the path JENKINS_HOME.

Where is JENKINS_HOME when jenkins is installed via Homebrew? Or alternatively, how can one nuke an entire installation of jenkins installed via Homebrew? brew uninstalling and installing did not do the trick.

Comment: I believe it is in ~/.jenkins from the user you installed it as.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to http://jenkins_master:port/configure and the first line is your Home directory. Log into the machine and go to that location, there you can find the config.xml and change Security to disabled.

By default, JENKINS_HOME is at `~/.jenkins`.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, can this be changed? thanks