# How to move Jenkins from a macmini to another macbook

Tags: jenkins

How can I copy the old Jenkins project on a mac mini to another MacBook. I found there is a tutorial online on windows(copy the whole Jenkins folder to another pc). But I don't find the folder on mac os.

It says location it on /Users/chenyuchang/.jenkins but I don't find it.
[image]

Many thanks

Comment: How did you install? The [`/configure` page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37237997/598141) should tell you where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ian mentioned you should be able to check the Jenkins workspace location in Configure section in Jenkins. Also, note that .jenkins is a hidden directory, so make sure hidden directories are visible in the finder.

Comment: Many thanks! Didn't know that it's a hidden folder.